# How to recode missing values in R

Tags: r, stata

How can I change this stata code to be able to run in R:
the goal is to recode missing values and generate "missing" dummies for some of the entries.

```
recode chethnic_tab .=-999
bys childid: egen tempethnic=max(chethnic_tab)
replace chethnic_tab=tempethnic if chethnic_tab==-999
recode chethnic_tab -999=.
*religion
recode chldrel_tab .=-999
bys childid: egen temprel=max(chldrel_tab)
replace chldrel_tab=temprel if chldrel_tab==-999
recode chldrel_tab -999=.
```

I tried asking chatGPT but the code it gives me in response doesnt run

Comment: Don't rely on chatGPT for well polished code

Comment: Provide example input data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

## Example data

```
df <- data.frame(childid = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                 chethnic_tab = c(1, NA, 1, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 chldrel_tab = c(3, NA, 3, 1, NA, 1, NA,NA,NA)
                 )
```

## To translate your Stata code to R

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(chethnic_tab:chldrel_tab, ~replace_na(.x, -999))) %>% 
  mutate(across(chethnic_tab:chldrel_tab, ~max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
         .by = childid) %>% 
  mutate(across(chethnic_tab:chldrel_tab, ~na_if(.x, -999)))

 childid chethnic_tab chldrel_tab
1       1            1           3
2       1            1           3
3       1            1           3
4       2            2           1
5       2            2           1
6       2            2           1
7       3           NA          NA
8       3           NA          NA
9       3           NA          NA
```

However, you may not really need to code missing values in R.

## Simple R code

```
df %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(chethnic_tab:chldrel_tab,   ~max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
         .by = childid)
```

You will get warnings if you have all missing for some 'childid': ! no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf. I would just ignore it.